# 502 error in production

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to deploy the latest changes to my django app, and I keep getting 502 errors. When I look at the logs, I only have this error in the Django logs: `Error: %s <type 'exceptions.NameError'>`. There's nothing in the Nginx error logs, and the access logs only show the 502 error. It runs fine in development, and it uses the same pip packages as development. How do I debug this?

**Edit:** This is actually an updated deployment. I had deployed it before without an issue, but something in my latest changes causes it to fail. I just need to know what that change was, but I can't find anything in the logs that would explain it.

I'm using Nginx, Django 1.8, Passenger, and Python 3.4. The server's running Ubuntu 14.04.

Sorry for the vague question, but I don't even know why this is happening.

**Edit 2:** <s>It looks like there's actually something in the Nginx error log now. It's still vague, but at least it says something now. For the record, it's `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'results' referenced before assignment` in `passenger_wsgi.py`. I'm still clueless about why that's popping up now, but at least it's something to work with.</s> Never mind. It's there, but that's just a result of the actual error, not the cause of it. However, the reason I asked this question is because I couldn't find anything in the logs, and now I've actually found something. So, for those of you looking for error logs:

- Check your Nginx config files (`nginx.conf`, config files in `sites-available`) for the line `error_log` and check that.
- If you're using Passenger and Django, check your passenger_wsgi.py to see if you've included logging. If so, check where it outputs.

It looks like my issue is out of the scope of this question, but I'd still like to leave it up in case anyone else has trouble finding log files.

Comment: Have you set `allowed_hosts`?

Comment: Yes. In `settings.py`, it says `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [*']`. I forgot to mention that I deployed it without a problem before, this only popped up in the latest deployment.

Comment: Any errors when you acces django shell with `python manage.py shell`?

Comment: Nope. I'm able to get into the shell.

Comment: I imagine it's a typo, but your `settings.py` should be `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*",]`

Comment: That didn't help. I'm still getting a 502 error.